# Program is getting existed without logging any exception while reading device twin using .net core

Tags: c#, azure, azure-iot-hub

**Technology around this question are**: `Azure IOT Hub` and `C#`

**Application Framework**: .NET Core 2.1

Functionality I am trying to achieve is to read the `device twin` properties of `device` of a `IOT Hub` as follow

```
string DeviceId = configuration["Azure:DeviceId"];
string DeviceKey = configuration["Azure:DeviceKey"];
string deviceConnectionString = "HostName=xxxxxx.azure-devices.net;DeviceId={0};SharedAccessKey={1}";
deviceConnectionString = string.Format(deviceConnectionString,
                    DeviceId, DeviceKey);
ConfigHubClient = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(deviceConnectionString, TransportType.Mqtt_WebSocket_Only);

try
{
     var twin = await ConfigHubClient.GetTwinAsync();
     deviceTwinConfig = twin.Properties.Desired; // debugger never comes here
}
catch()
{
    --Logging exceptions code here
}
```

No exceptions thrown or logged.

Answer (score 1):

If the method performing the above code is a `void` method and the code that calls the method is the entry point of the application (such as the `Main` method in a console app), then the code will return to the calling method (i.e. `Main`) when the `await ConfigHubClient.GetTwinAsync()` is performed.

If this is the case, try changing the return value of the method from `void` to `Task` and wait on the call in the entry point method.

Hope it helps!